# Start text from new line

Tags: angular

I have two string. and I want to display the second string from new line. But I have to use only one variable in html.

```
let msg = "hello"+\n+"how r u";
```

I have to concat two string but start the second string from new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have not described your problem completely, one possible and simple  way is to use `split` function.

```
<p>{{msg.split('\n')[0]}}</p>
<p>{{msg.split('\n')[1]}}</p>
```

Answer (score 10):

Import `DomSanitizationService`.

```
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

in constructor of class do this

```
constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
    this.msg = "Hello" + "<br/>" + "How are you?";
    this.msg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.msg);
}
```

Use `msg` in the template as shown below

```
<p [innerHTML]="msg"></p>
```